# Using $emit in angular 1.5 component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using angular 1.5 component and need to call function in parent controller from when $emit in child component. How we can do this?

Example:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    controllerName.$inject = [];

    function controllerName() {
       var _this = this;
       function toBeCalledOnEmit() {//some code}
       var vm = {
          toBeCalledOnEmit: toBeCalledOnEmit
       }
       angular.extend(_this, vm);
    }

    angular.module('moduleName', [
    ]).component('parentComponenet', {
        templateUrl: 'templateUrl',
        controller: 'controllerName'
    }).controller('controllerName', controllerName);

})(angular);
```

child component:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    childController.$inject = [];

    function childController() {
       //needs $emit here
    }

    angular.module('childModuleName', [
    ]).component('childComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'templateUrl',
        controller: 'childController'
    }).controller('childController', childController);

})(angular);
```

Comment: I have used $emit, $broadcast and $on before 1.5, but in 1.5 component we are not using $scope or $rootscope. How to achieve this without $scope? In docs $emit is using with $scope.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I prefer working with a separate event service that exposes subscribe and notify functions. But if you prefer to emit from the child component then it would look like this:

#### Child Component

```
    (function (angular) {
    'use strict';

      function childController($scope) {
       $scope.$emit("someEvent", args); 
      }

      angular.module('childModuleName', [
      ]).component('childComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'templateUrl',
        controller: ['$scope', childController]
      });

    })(angular);
```

#### Parent Component

```
    (function (angular) {
    'use strict';


      function controllerName($scope) {
         var _this = this;

         function toBeCalledOnEmit(event, args) {
            //some code
         }
         $scope.on('someEvent', toBeCalledOnEmit);

         var vm = {
            toBeCalledOnEmit: toBeCalledOnEmit
         }
         angular.extend(_this, vm);
      }

      angular.module('moduleName', [
      ]).component('parentComponent', {
          templateUrl: 'templateUrl',
          controller: ['$scope', controllerName]
      });

    })(angular);
```

Comment: using $rootScope like @Praveen Poonia did is a good idea when we want a single place of notifying and subscribing (although, as far as I know, $rootScope and $scope will be deprecated in Angular 2).

Comment: I wouldn't advise using `$rootScope`. After doing some reading it would seem that's potential for a memory leak. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830679/why-do-we-use-rootscope-broadcast-in-angularjs) for further details.

Comment: `this` is undefined.. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48691233/766570

Comment: What does the `angular.extend()` part do? Is it just binding the event payload so it becomes a property on the parent component...?

Answer (score 3):

Code is attached below:

1. Child Component:

   ```
   (function (angular) {
       'use strict';

   childController.$inject = ['$scope'];

   function childController($scope) {

      //needs $emit here
   $scope.$emit("topic-123", 'any message'); 
   }

   angular.module('childModuleName', [
   ]).component('childComponent', {
       templateUrl: 'templateUrl',
       controller: 'childController'
   }).controller('childController', childController);
   ```

   })(angular);
2. Parent Component:

   ```
   (function (angular) {
   'use strict';

   controllerName.$inject = ['$scope'];

   function controllerName($scope) {
      var _this = this;
      function toBeCalledOnEmit() {//some code}
      var vm = {
         toBeCalledOnEmit: toBeCalledOnEmit
      }

      $scope.$on('topic-123', function(event, msg) {
     // @TODO  
     toBeCalledOnEmit();
      });

      angular.extend(_this, vm);
   }

   angular.module('moduleName', [
   ]).component('parentComponenet', {
       templateUrl: 'templateUrl',
       controller: 'controllerName'
   }).controller('controllerName', controllerName);
   ```

   })(angular);

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this using $rootScope. It works fine in my case -

**child component:**

```
(function (angular) {
 'use strict';

 childController.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

 function childController($rootScope) {
   $rootScope.$emit('myEvent',$scope.data)
 }
})(angular);
```

**Parent Component:**

```
(function (angular) {
 'use strict';

 controllerName.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

 function controllerName($rootScope) {
   var _this = this;
   function toBeCalledOnEmit() {//some code}
   var vm = {
      toBeCalledOnEmit: toBeCalledOnEmit
   }
   $rootScope.$on('myEvent', function(event, msg) {
     toBeCalledOnEmit();
   });
   angular.extend(_this, vm);
 }
})(angular);
```