# how to access this inside an event receiver angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eventemitter, angular1.6

I was going over [this tutorial](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/) to implement sending/receiving broadcast messages in my angular 1.5 app.

so inside a controller I have this:

```
  update(){
    this.$rootScope.$broadcast('language_changed');
  }
```

and in another controller I got this:

```
    $rootScope.$on('language_changed', function (event, data){
        this.updateStore();  <--- this here is undefined
    });

  }

  updateStore() {
      this.store = {
          ..
          language_id: this.LanguageService.get(),

        }
  }
```

I'm wondering how can I get hold of `this` inside the broadcast. [This trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37292156/766570) didn't work

Comment: Whether it is upward-downward controller. Can you put your both controller code and HTML where controller defines.

Comment: See linked tutorial.. the placement of the controllers relative to one another is irrelevant considering that I'm using $rootScope

Comment: try updateStore() without this

Comment: yes it should I think because when you call event upward you should use $emit and when you call event downward you should use $broadcast.

Comment: see answer guys

Answer (score 2):

The answer that you provided is not a proper solution, you need to understand what are you doing, making hacks is not a solution. Please read the following article to get a basic knowledge about the difference between this and $scope [this vs $scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)

Important to know aswell concerning angular events:

**$emit - Sends event up the angular three of scopes**

**$broadcast - Sends event down the angular three**

Furthermore, please take a look at the following snippet: [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/84ut3am1/)

When you have two controllers, you don't need to both $broadcast the event from $rootScope and listen to it $on $rootScope, it can be simply listened to on a $scope level, $rootScope dependency injection is not needed. Check out the following:

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.broadCastEvent = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('language_changed');
  };
});
```

Let's say that we want to broadcast an event when user clicks a button. The event is sent down the angular three of scopes, so your controller that is listening to this event can listen it on scope level, without the $rootScope dependency injection, something like this:

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl2', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('language_changed', function() {
   $scope.eventFired = !$scope.eventFired;
   });
})
```

The other case is when you want to $emit the event (send it up the angular three), then you would need to inject $rootScope to the controller that will be listening to that event, because only $rootScope can listen on a event that is being **$emit**ed from $rootScope. Check out the following:

Controller $emiting the event:

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
 $scope.emitEvent = function() {
  $rootScope.$emit('language_changed');
 };
});
```

Controller catching the event:

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl2', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('language_changed', function() {
   $scope.eventFired = !$scope.eventFired;
 });
})
```

Try playing with the snippet a bit, look what happends if you want to $emit the event from $rootScope and try to catch it on the $scope level.

Hope this clarifies it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

solution was simple, using the javascript `bind` hack:

```
$rootScope.$on('language_changed', function (event, data){
    this.updateStore();
}.bind(this));  <-- bind makes the inner this same as outer this..
```

Comment: i got a feeling that some angular purist will wait for me in the parking lot to beat me up over this though 