# How to allow a function in a component to access factory imported in constructor?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, components, angular-meteor

I have been trying to share data between components and followed advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033940/how-to-pass-data-between-child-components-in-angular-1-5-not-using-scope) to make a store.

It all works great from within my components constructor but I can't figure out how to give the functions similar access.

```
class Home {
  constructor($scope, $reactive, Store) {
    'ngInject';

    $reactive(this).attach($scope);

    this.selectedDate = Store.get().selectedDate;
}
```

That all works, but accessing the Store here doesn't work:

```
nextDay(){
    'ngInject';
    Store.set({selectedDate: moment(this.selectedDate).add(1, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD')});
    console.log('nextDay');
}
```

I have tried attaching Store to $reactive, I have tried this.Store and passing Store as an agrument to nextDay() but can't figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the services(injected things) on the Class

for example if you wanna use Store assign this.Store = Store
and then you can use it from all the methods in the class as this.Store

```
  class Home {
      constructor($scope, $reactive, Store) {
        'ngInject';
        this.Store = Store;
        this.$reactive = $reactive;
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.$reactive(this).attach($scope);

        this.selectedDate = this.Store.get().selectedDate;
      }

      nextDay(){
        this.Store.set({selectedDate: moment(this.selectedDate).add(1, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD')});
        console.log('nextDay');

      }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought it would be something simple!