# How to communicate between 2 component - sibling components(Angular 1.5.8)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey I have the following component tree: I have a root component called rules and two sons components called: rulesPanel & rulesEditor.

Now I can create a communication between son and mother component:

rulesEditor can call to rules component and jump an event on him.

rulesPanel can call to rules component and jump an event on him.

I want to have a communication between the 2 brothers:

rulesEditor and rulesPanel.

I don't want to use $scope or $broadcast, I want to do it through the bindings of the component himself.
I have tried to think of way of doing so, but all I got is that I can call to upper level but not to a parallel level.

**Edit:**
My Question is different from the possible duplication,
I don't want to pass a data, I want to execute a function in one component and then execute another function in the sibling component as a result of a click function in the brother component.

Here is my code and what I have achieved so far:

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

angular.module('app').component('rules', {
  template: `
            <rules-panel dial-mom="$ctrl.receivePhoneCall(message)">
            </rules-panel>
            <rules-editor>
            </rules-editor>`,
  bindings: {
  },
  controller: rulesController,
});

function rulesController(){
  var self = this;
  self.receivePhoneCall = function(message){
    console.log("Hello Son");
    console.log("I got your message:",message)
  }
  console.log("rulesController")
}

angular.module('app').component('rulesPanel', {
  template: `<h1>rulesPanel</h1>
              <button ng-click="$ctrl.callMom()">CallMom</button>
     <button ng-click="$ctrl.CallBrother()">CallBrother</button>`,
  bindings: {
    dialMom: '&'
  },
  controller: rulesPanelController,
});

function rulesPanelController(){
  var self = this;
  console.log("rulesPanelController");
  self.callMom = function(){
    console.log("Call mom");
    self.dialMom({message:"Love you mom"});
  }
  
   self.CallBrother = function(){
    console.log("Call brother");
  }
}

angular.module('app').component('rulesEditor', {
  template: '<h1>rulesEditor</h1>',
  bindings: {
  },
  controller: rulesEditorController,
});

function rulesEditorController(){
  console.log("rulesEditorController")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  
  <rules></rules>
  
</div>
```

Comment: This can be done through parent component or through common service. It depends on particular case which way is better. If there's only one 'rules', the service should be good.

Comment: I have a parent component called rules, I don't need a service for this.
Can you give me an example of how a click event occur in son component can trigger an event on brother component?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: In general in MV* frameworks events aren't communicated sideways or down. Events are communicated upward; model values are communicated downward. Having state changes in more than one place violates the [Single Source of Truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth) principle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data between sibling components without using $scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033940/how-to-pass-data-between-sibling-components-without-using-scope)

Comment: my mistake this is realy a duplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a semi Angular 2 component approach. Meaning you can use Input/output approach to achieve this.

I will give you an example and you can take it from there.

Let's say you have a header and a main component.

In your header component where you want to notify the main you can raise an event like this:

```
.component('headerComponent', {
  template: `
    <h3>Header component</h3>
    <a ng-class="{'btn-primary': $ctrl.view === 'list'}" ng-click="$ctrl.setView('list')">List</a>
    <a ng-class="{'btn-primary': $ctrl.view === 'table'}" ng-click="$ctrl.setView('table')">Table</a>
  `,
  controller: function() {
    this.setView = function(view) {
      this.view = view
      this.onViewChange({$event: {view: view}})
    }
  },
  bindings: {
    view: '<',
    onViewChange: '&'
  }
})
```

With binding view: '<' we specify that header component will be able to read outer something and bind it as view property of the own controller.

Header controller can be used like this:

```
<header-component view="root.view" on-view-change="root.view = $event.view"></header-component>
```

On the other hand main in simpler, it only needs to define input it accepts:

```
.component('mainComponent', {
  template: `
    <h4>Main component</h4>
    Main view: {{ $ctrl.view }}
  `,
  bindings: {
    view: '<'
  }
})
```

And finally it all wired together:

```
<header-component view="root.view" on-view-change="root.view = $event.view"></header-component>
<main-component view="root.view"></main-component>
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BzftoYHvVtuQdICnHk0P?p=preview).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply,
But this planker doesn't answer my question
I don't want to pass a data, I want to execute a function in one component and then execute another function in the sibling component as a result of a click function in the brother component.