# passing data from same level components in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, components, angularjs-components

I have a question on how we can pass data from one component to another without $scope or $rootScope but something similar to Angular (2/4). Let's assume that I have three components:

- rootComponent: Entry point of the application
- phoneListComponent: Display list of phones
- phoneDetailComponent: Display the details of the selected phone

rootComponent source code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('phonecatApp').
component('appRoot', {
    templateUrl: 'app-root.template.html',
    controller: [
        function appRootController(){
            var self = this;
        }
    ]
});
```

phoneListComponent source code:

```
'use strict';

// Register `phoneList` component, along with its associated controller and template
angular.module('phoneList').component('phoneList', {
    //Note: the URL is relative to our 'index.html' file
    templateUrl: 'phone-list/phone-list.template.html',
    controller: [
        function PhoneListController() {
            var self = this;
            self.phones = [
                {
                    "name": "Huawei P9 lite",
                    "description": "This is one hell of a phone",
                    "price": "250€"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Samsung S8",
                    "description": "Great phone but really expensive",
                    "price": "700€"
                }
            ]

            self.select = function(phone){
                self.selected=phone;
            }

        }
    ]
});
```

phoneDetailComponent source code:

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('phoneDetail').
            component('phoneDetail', {
                templateUrl: 'phone-detail/phone-detail.template.html',
                bindings: {
                    selected: '<'
                },
                controller: [
                    function phoneDetailController(){
                        var self = this;
                    }
                ],
            });
```

You can see that each component is declared in its own module, and *phoneList module* and *phoneDetail module* are registered in *phoneCatApp module*.

Since components have their own isolated scopes, I can't pass the selected attribute from phoneList to phoneDetail. What are the possible solutions knowing that I seek loosely coupling and no $scope or $rootScope?

I already saw this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033940/how-to-pass-data-between-sibling-components-without-using-scope) on StackOverflow but seems to me that my modules won't work if there's not a parent that orchestrate above them, which can be not always the case.

Thank you

Comment: You might want to define a service and inject it into both components.  This way you can define common methods related to management of `phones` array.  Alternatively, you could inject `$rootScope` and store `phones` as `$rootScope.phones`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could you use two strategies:

- The first one is passing a callback to your child components (through bindings) from
  your root component so you will be aware when the value changed and
  then do what you need to do.
- Another approach could be using an
  angular service which is a singleton so you can watch a specific
  value inside your controller and then do something when it changes.

In this case, I suggest the first one.