# How to send data from the Component to the parent in AngularJS 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angularjs-components, angularjs-bindings

I have two tabs as a component, which contains some input field, when I press the **SAVE** button I want to get the value of them and save it to the server. The problem is **SAVE** function is in the `index.js` (parent) and the **Input fields** are in the `TestComponent.js`. I couldn't find the way to get the values from the component and send it to the Parent Controller (indexController.js).

I also tried to use the [binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component), for example to save all the data as an object and send the object to the `indexController.js` but unfortunately I wasn't successful.

Please also take a look at the [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/X8X7F3u0ZH2uWFtGk7XO?p=preview) for the example.

Can someone help me with that.

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="heroApp">

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">

  <!-- Component Started -->
  <md-tabs>
    <tab-component> </tab-component>
  </md-tabs>
  <!-- Component Ended -->

  <button type="submit" ng-click="save()"> Save </button>

</div>

</body>
```

**index.js**

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('heroApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl() {
  var vm = this;

  this.onStatusChange = function(data) {
    vm.mandatoryFilesIncluded = data;
  };

  this.save = function() {
    vm.requestInProgress = true;
    vm.Upload.upload({
      url: someURL,
      arrayKey: '',
      data: {
        file: vm.files,
        name: vm.data.name,
        title: vm.data.title,
        description: vm.data.description,
      }
    }).then(function(response){
        alert("data is uploaded.");
    });
  };

});
})(window.angular);
```

**tabComponent.html**

```
<!-- Upload Tab-->
<md-tab id="picTab" label="Pic">
  <div layout-gt-xs="row" layout-align="start center">

    <md-input-container style="padding-left: 0">
      <md-button>
        <md-icon class="material-icons">attach_file</md-icon>
      </md-button>
    </md-input-container>

  </div>
</md-tab>


<!-- Info Tab-->
<md-tab id="infoTab" label="Info">
  <md-content class="md-margin">

    <div layout-gt-sm="row">
      <!-- Name -->
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input ng-model="vm.data.name" name="name" required>
      </md-input-container>

      <!-- Title -->
      <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input ng-model="vm.data.title" name="title" required>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>

    <!-- Description field -->
    <div layout="row">
      <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea ng-model="vm.data.description" name="descriptionField" rows="1"></textarea>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
  </md-content>
</md-tab>
```

**tabComponent.js**

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('heroApp').component('tabComponent', {
  templateUrl: 'tabComponent.html',
  controller: myComponentController,
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  bindings: {
    statusChange: '&',
  }
});
})(window.angular);

function myComponentController() {
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.mandatoryFilesIncluded = false;
}
```

Comment: Better paste the relevant code here in addition to the link.

Comment: you can broadcast an event from your child component and your parent component will listen to it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526318/efficient-way-to-communicate-components-or-directives-in-angular-1-x this link might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `save` button fires in main controller, you can define `vm.data` into controller and bind it to component:

```
bindings: {
  data: '=',
}
```

and `tab-component` pass data as:

```
 <tab-component data="vm.data"> </tab-component>
```

So any change of `vm.data` inside component will be reflected in controller too.

<kbd>[Working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/914MqdFFYLlvi5amFCPJ?p=preview)</kbd>